# How to find unused code in a huge codebase

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, dead-code

It's a java springboot application with intellij.

The problem is:

1. intellij makes mistakes when it comes to finding unused code (marking unused as used or vica versa)
2. The codebase contains huge amount of custom hacks*

*by custom hack I mean that class instantiation seems completely random like:
-using @Autowired
-using getBean
-using @Autowired on a collection of interface implementations and just refering the instance by the index (lol)

```
@Autowired
List<MyInterface> myList
public doSomething(){
myList.get(0).calculate()
}
```

-using reflection:

```
val classToInstantiate = "<some_prefix>"+getMiddlePartWithSomeStupidLogic()+"<parameter_as_suffix>"
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(classToInstantiate);
cls.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(params..)
```

I feel that every package or class is written by different developer.

I feel completely impossible to explore the dead code in an easy way. So I started to do it by hand - like searching every field/class/method name by hand - but it would take weeks and it is still errorprone.

So is there an easy and fast way for this?

Comment: *"So is there an **easy and fast** way for this?"* - Probably no.

Comment: Will it be worth it? Sounds like a big chance  of introducing bugs.